# AngularJS orderBy with named elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So, I have a JSON named frutas as showed below. AngularJS orders it automatically by the fruit name, but I need it ordered by 'order'.
When I try to order it with:

```
ng-repeat="fruta in frutas | orderBy:'order'"
```

I get no result. Why? How can I fix that?

```
{
cacau: {cod: 2244, order: 3},
abacaxi: {cod: 18967, order: 2},
bacuri: {cod: 124, order: 1},
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`orderBy` expects an array to operate with. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

If

```
{
   cacau: {cod: 2244, order: 3},
   abacaxi: {cod: 18967, order: 2},
   bacuri: {cod: 124, order: 1},
}
```

is what `frutas` contains then this is the reason why `orderBy` is not working. Please modify the data in such a way to be an array, because at the moment is an object.

You can test if the data is an array with
[Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) method.

Comment: You can even use `typeof` to get the data type of a variable